In Ruby, how do I find a value in an array of hashes?
I am trying to get a value in an array of hashes in Ruby. Given the following information below:
  # array_of_hash_objects will look something like this:
  # [
  #   { name: 'Ruby', is_my_favorite?: true },
  #   { name: 'JavaScript', is_my_favorite?: false },
  #   { name: 'HTML', is_my_favorite?: false }
  # ]

I simply want to return the name where the value is true. My thoughts were to use the collect method in an expression like this: array_of_hash_objects.collect { |name, fave| if fave[:is_my_favorite?] == true }.compact
However, when I try this in irb, I get the following error:
NoMethodError:
undefined method `[]' for nil
I cannot for the life of me figure out what I've done wrong.
I have tried using both the collect and select methods with the same result above.

The reason you get this error is because you can't refer the |name, fave| in the loop. Because you are looping in an array, an array can only have value, not a key. In your case try: array_of_hash_objects.collect { |hash| hash[:name] if hash[:is_my_favorite?] == true }.compact

array_of_hash_objects.select { |item| item[:is_my_favorite?] }.pluck(:name)

If you turn the hashes into instances of a custom class with appropriate methods, you'll get array_of_objects.find(&:is_my_favorite?).name

There is filter_map exactly for this use case:
[
  { name: 'Ruby', is_my_favorite?: true },
  { name: 'JavaScript', is_my_favorite?: false },
  { name: 'HTML', is_my_favorite?: false }
].filter_map do |hash|
  hash[:name] if hash[:is_my_favorite?]
end

#=> ["Ruby"]


You want something like this:
[
  { name: 'Ruby', is_my_favorite?: true },
  { name: 'JavaScript', is_my_favorite?: false },
  { name: 'HTML', is_my_favorite?: false }
].select { |x| x[:is_my_favorite?] }

Note that values of :is_my_favorite? are boolean, and select returns entries in the array for which the block evaluates to a truthy value.
And in Ruby, a block (or method, or any scope, really) implicitly evaluates to the value of the last expression/line in the block.

This returns the entire hash and not the desired array of names.

A more direct approach would be Enumerable#find, which accepts a block and either returns the first object in the sequence for which the block is truthy, or nil.
If you wanted to do this in one-line, you could also couple this with the safe-navigation operator to transparently deal with the nil return, like so:
# Accessing the whole object via #find
hash = array_of_hash_objects.find { |hash| hash[:is_my_favorite?] }
p hash # => { name: 'Ruby', is_my_favorite?: true }

# Getting just the name via #find + safe-navigation
name = array_of_hash_objects.find { |hash| hash[:is_my_favorite?] }&.fetch(:name)
p name # => "Ruby"

# Getting the name via #find, without safe-navigation
hash = array_of_hash_objects.find { |hash| hash[:is_my_favorite?] } || {}
name = hash[:name]
p name # => "Ruby"


As to why your initial code failed, Enumerable#collect expects a block of this form:
enumerable.collect { |element| ... }

...where element will be one of the elements in the collection, in sequence. In your case, it will be one of the whole hashes in your list. However, in your code, you supplied two arguments:
array_of_hash_objects.collect { |name, fave| ... }

Unfortunately, due to how proc's work, this will not raise an error, but will silently set your second (and any more arguments you supply) to nil. This is why you received an error saying undefined method '[]' for nil, exactly because you're using [] on a nil value!

The comment of @darkinside is correct. You just missed hash[:name]
array_of_hash_objects.collect { |hash| hash[:name] if hash[:is_my_favorite?] == true }.compact

However, there are many ways to achieve what you want, for example
array_of_hash_objects.reduce([]) { |acc, obj| obj[:is_my_favorite?] ? acc.push(obj[:name]) : acc }


Method 1: simply using the iterating method each on the array and a if condition block
 array_of_hash_objects = [
     { name: 'Ruby', is_my_favorite?: true },
     { name: 'JavaScript', is_my_favorite?: false },
     { name: 'HTML', is_my_favorite?: false }
  ]
  
array_of_hash_objects.each { |hash_object|
  if hash_object[:is_my_favorite?]
    puts hash_object[:name]
  end
}

Method 2: using the filter method select on the array where you set your condition for filter, then iterate through the filtered array and return the result
array_of_hash_objects.select{ |entry|
  entry[:is_my_favorite?] == true
}.each{ |filteredentry|
  puts filteredentry[:name]
}

using collect ( aka map) seems unfit, because it returns an (1:1)  one to one mapping.
Basically collect iterates through the array and returns what you give ( return ) based on a condition, if you didn't (give) return anything - the value will be nil for that entry. eg: [ "Ruby", nil, nil ]
we can use an if condition to check is_my-favorite? is true and return the name, then our collect returns an array which contains nil , But we can use compact to filter out the nil values.
filtered = array_of_hash_objects.collect{ |entry|
puts entry
  if entry[:is_my_favorite?] == true
    entry[:name]
  end
}

puts filtered


While I was not the one that downvoted, I assume the downvote is based on the fact that the request is "I simply want to return the name where the value [of :is_my_favorite] is true"; however the options you provided will return: 1) the full content of array_of_hash_objects ; 2) [{ name: 'Ruby', is_my_favorite?: true }]; 3) nil. None of which result in satisfying the desired outcome.
